# Robert Giesecke's Unmanaged Exports and MSBuild infinite loop

Tags: c#, msbuild, export, unmanaged

We are running into an `MSBuild` issue when using "Unmanaged Exports" from Visual Studio 2012. It seems that, for whatever reason `MSBuild` is getting into an infinite loop. When the link to "Unmanaged Export" is removed, everything seems to compile in a fine way.

When we either try to limit the amount of code or move the code into a referenced assembly, everything works fine too.

We want to keep all the code in the same assembly in this case. Any suggestions or guidance are appreciated.

Thanks.